# Get window height to decimal point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get the height of my window. Hence, I use `window.innerHeight`.

However, this return an integer and I would like a precise value (float). I though to use `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height` but this means to add some css to fill entirely the window. Such like that:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

How can I get the the height of the window to decimal point?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want it to be a float (other then having more precision)? I think that the integer should work just fine. If you must have a float, just cast innerHeight to float

Comment: Also, does `getBoundingClientRect()` actually return  floats? I'm always getting integers.

Comment: In fact, I need to be precise because I want to set the top position of a modal and actually because of 0.3px (for example) I got an overflow and a scrollbar appears (I know I could use overflow:hidden) @PhantomSpooks

Comment: Yes, getBoundingClientRect() returns floats if needed @RoboRobok

Comment: @PierBJX I know that it does when an element is actually defined to have float dimensions, but for window height? I don't think so.

Comment: @RoboRobok. But when you set padding to 0, margin to 0, width to 100% and height to 100% to your html, body (see the css in my question) and you go to console debug and you inspect the html you see float value. So it means that the window height/widht has float number, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) and `body`'s height to `100%` programmatically, get the height, then remove the inline style so as not to make any lasting changes:

```js
function getPreciseHeight() {
  document.documentElement.style.height = "100%";
  document.body.style.height = "100%";

  const height = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  document.documentElement.style.removeProperty('height');
  document.body.style.removeProperty('height');
  return height;
}

console.log("Normal:", document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)



console.log("Fixed:", getPreciseHeight())
```

```html
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. With the snippet in stackoverflow, it makes less sense because it is encapsulated in 200px.  It was more or less what I was doing with the style but at least there is no impact :)